# Resize terminal from command?

Tags: shell, resize, terminal

I'm using cygwin but, is it possible to resize the terminal window via a command rather than doing it myself every time I open it? Some scripts I want to be a certain size for my own benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't resize the default terminal, since it's just windows' native 'cmd'. Alternatively, I saw this new addition of late: http://georgik.sinusgear.com/2011/11/23/mintty-resizable-terminal-for-windows/. Not particularly sure whether you can resize that reminal from commandline though. It's still a windows console application.

Comment: Yeah I am using that version. That sucks that you can't resize it with a command but oh well.

Comment: Judging from it's manpage: -s, --size COLS,ROWS
Set the default size of the window in character columns and rows. If you try spawning a new terminal with those parameters you can kind of emulate the behaviour that you want, but it's more of a hack, rather than a solution :)

Answer (score 12):

The 'CSI t' sequence can be used for that on xterm-compatible terminals. Search https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html for XTWINOPS for details.

For example, to resize to 50 rows and 80 columns.

```
echo -ne '\e[8;50;80t'
```

Comment: Do you mean resizes to a height of 80 and a width of 50 characters?

Comment: Yes, the height comes first, so `50;80` would have been a more useful example. :)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on `bash.exe` :

```
mode.com 80,50
```

to set 80 columns and 50 rows.
Note that `mode` and `mode.com` are not the same in this case.

Comment: @J-Dizzle : maybe you wrote `mode 80,50` instead? Anyway, more details about what happens could help us in troubleshooting.

Comment: good thoughts I was using mintty.exe. 'mode.com' works great for bash.exe my apologies!

Comment: No problem, @J-Dizzle , confussion was possible as long as Windows includes another `mode` command. I have edited my answer to reflect.